# How to skip Windows Credentials Manager using GitPython

Tags: python, git, gitpython

I am using GitPython to execute `git` commands that require authentication such as `git clone`. I am using Windows. My configured credential helper is Windows' Credential Manager and I don't want to change it. That's why when the program runs, I enter my credentials via a GUI which is ok. But during tests, I want to be able to provide them statically, I don't want to enter them via or GUI or any interactive way. Also I don't want to change global configuration for `credential.helper` even for a limited time (like during runtime) because that might have some side effects. Is there a way I can handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `_persistent_git_options` attribute of Git class with monkey patching. This way, `git` word in the commands are followed by `-c credential.helper=` by default.

```py
import git as gitpy
'''Keep the original __init__ implementation of gitpy.cmd.Git'''
old__init__ = gitpy.cmd.Git.__init__

'''
Method redefining ``__init__`` method of ``gitpy.cmd.Git``.

The new definition wraps original implementation and adds
"-c credential.helper=" to persistent git options so that
it will be included in every git command call.
'''
def new__init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    old__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    self._persistent_git_options = ["-c", "credential.helper="]


'''Set __init__ implementation of gitpy.cmd.Git to that is implemented above'''
gitpy.cmd.Git.__init__ = new__init__
```